# Taylor series convergence with natural logs

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I am working on this problem.

Find Taylor series of function $f(x)=\ln(x)$ at $a = 6$.

$$f(x) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n (x- 6)^n$$

I seem to be having trouble with the interval of convergence can someone show me how to do it.

Comment: Do you know how to find the interval of convergence for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$, for an arbitrary series?

Comment: Not really this could be my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\ln(x) = \int\frac{1}{x}dx\\
\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{6 - (6 - x)} = \frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{1 - \frac{-(x - 6)}{6}} = \frac{1}{6}\sum_0^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(x - 6)^n}{6^n}
$$

This is a geometric series and thus converges when the common ratio: $\frac{x - 6}{6}$ is smaller than one:

$$
\left|\frac{x - 6}{6}\right| < 1 \\
|x - 6| < 6 \\
0 < x < 12
$$

Oh, and if you want the taylor series then you need to *integrate* the above:

$$
\ln(x) = \ln(6) + \frac{1}{6}\sum_0^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(x - 6)^{n + 1}}{(n+1)6^n} = \ln(6) -\sum_1^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\frac{(x - 6)^n}{6^{n}}
$$

Notice that the addition of $\ln(6)$ is necessary to make this correct (since if you plug in $x = 6$ to the sum, you get zero).  Note that the sum became negative because you get $(-1)^{n - 1} = -(-1)^n$ and the $\frac{1}{6}$ went away because you have $\frac{1}{6^{n - 1}} = \frac{1}{6^n\frac{1}{6}} = \frac{6}{6^n}$ which cancels the divide by $6$ in front of the original sum.

Comment: Why does the $C$ vanish and why choose 6 and not 1

Comment: The $C$ is part of the indefinite integral.  If I want $\ln(x)$ then I differentiate and thus $\frac{1}{x}$ is all I need.  The $6$ is because you wanted the Taylor series about $x_0 = 6$.

Comment: Thanks I have been banging my head over this for an hour now I can bang my head over the next one.

Comment: Your approach is right, but you got this bassackwards: $\ln(x) + C = \int \frac{dx}{x}$.  So you should find the series for $1/x$ and then *anti*differentiate.

Comment: @SpamIAm Yeah you're right, I was just thinking to myself: $\ln(6) \neq -\frac{1}{36}$.  You need to _integrate_ to find $\ln(x)$, _not_ differentiate...then the +C is _very_ important.

Comment: Right, your very first line is wrong: $\int \ln(x) dx = x \ln(x) - x + C$, not $1/x$.

Comment: I'll edit my answer so that it's correct.